# Tagmanager and iframe (track url)

Tags: iframe, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

How i can take url of page and send to UA if the code (Tagmanager) inserted in the page via iframe . Other variants insert the tracking code is not.

We post articles on an external site and yet get the overall statistics, but I'd like to break it for the articles.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly the url of the hosting page is passed as the referrer to the page hosted in the iframe. So you'd need to check if your page is indeed displayed in the frame and then pass the referring url as page url (via set fields in the Google Analytics tag). I'm frankly not sure if this works with every browser (just did a quick test with Chrome), but I guess it's the best solution (unless you can pass the page url in a query parameter to the iframe, which is a pretty foolproof solution).

Comment: thank you !!
I decided through a referral, but passed it as an additional parameter ..